# How can I get translation for a field of custom date

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, datetime

I am using the paragraphs module. I have a field which contains a date and time e.g. for events, which is added by an author. For the output I use a paragraph-twig-file and I have this:

```
<div class="timeline-date">
    {{ content.field_date }}
</div>
```

In the backend of Drupal I created a custom time "D, d.m.Y - H:i". The output is right e.g. "Fri, 24.08.2018 - 17:14", but my site is in german and not english. **So how, can I translate the day of week in german?** 
In my case [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/267046/55303) solution is not working

Comment: Try add field date between **{% trans %} ** and {% endtrans %}

Comment: It is not working. I got the following error message:  
"<em class="placeholder">Twig_Error_Syntax</em>: The text to be translated with &quot;trans&quot; can only contain references to simple variables in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Template\TwigTransTokenParser-&gt;checkTransString()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">10</em> of <em class="placeholder">themes/custom/.../.../.../.../paragraph--timeline-item.html.twig</em>). <pre class="backtrace">Drupal\Core\Template\TwigTransTokenParser-&gt;parse(Object)"

Comment: Can you get timestamp of this field date?

Comment: @MrD Why? Or maybe I do not understand your question. An author fill out the field. It is not a created date or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

In Twig, you can use built-in translation contexts. I had to output my dates in dutch format. The default formatting was:

```
{% set date = node.created.value|date("j") ~ ' ' ~ node.created.value|date("F") ~ ' ' ~ node.created.value|date("Y") %}
// now {{ date }} outputs: 8 August 2020
```

When I use translation contexts, it worked as expected:

```
{% set date = node.created.value|date("j") ~ ' ' ~ node.created.value|date("F")|t({}, {'context' : 'Long month name'}) ~ ' ' ~ node.created.value|date("Y") %}
// now {{ date }} outputs: 8 augustus 2020
```

More about translation contexts in Twig: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/translate-dates-twig-drupal-8

Answer (score -1):

You need to do something like below screenshot in my case i have translated months of date field in french language.

[image]

you have to search for day string for different language like fri ,replace the text for each language in text box then save to path admin/config/regional/translate